# When Job was blessed by God and received 7 sons and 3 daughters, did his wife have to raise these children from infancy? Or immediately adults?

Tags: job

From Job 42, where God blesses Job with children, does it say if they had to start from infancy or were immediately adults? All I find is the daughters' being fairer than any others in the land.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: The book of Job nowhere suggests that God blessed Job by giving him fully-grown, adult sons and daughters. After God blessed Job and he fathered seven sons and three daughters, Job lived for another 140 years (Job 42:12-17).  There is nothing in the Bible to suggest that the natural order of procreation was suspended.

Comment: Are suggesting that Job's second family were born adults??  Of course they were born as children!!

Comment: _After this lived Job an hundred and forty years, and saw his sons, and his sons' sons, even four generations. 17So Job died, being old and full of days._ 140 years is ample to have had two families, consecutively.

Comment: +1 from me as I *hoped* that they were given to Job fully grown. Can you imagine Mrs. Job being on board for all the nappies and raising yet another entire family after her first one had been wickedly destroyed? Maybe *that* God erased her memory, rejuvenated their bodies, etc. etc.  "Toying with humans" is not the characteristic of the Almighty God. ymmv

Comment: the text does not say that Mrs. Job was their mother.

Answer (score 1):

There is no example in the Bible of any human being born as an adult. Even Jesus Christ, the Son of God in Christian belief, was born as an infant. Many believe Eve may have been "born" from Adam's side  an adult, or that Adam was "born" from God's earth as adult; but even if taken literally, these cases are exceptional, being the first humans in creation. Nothing in the text suggests a miraculous creation of Job's children other than the apparent age of the couple. For those who place the time of story before the flood, even that problem does not require a miracle, because people lived much longer in those days. Indeed, the text provides us with a clear explanation for Job's wife's continued fertility, when it tells us that Job lived another 144 years after his trials concluded. (Job 42:16)

Incidentally, whether the story is literally true or not is debated. Some readers believe this part is a "fairy tale ending" added to the dialog to provide a comforting conclusion to an intentionally ambiguous lesson about the problem of evil in a world created by God.

One remaining issue, perhaps more realistic than whether they were born as adults: Mrs. Job is not mentioned in the ending. Are we certain that she is the mother of Job's new offspring? It may be that Mrs. Job was not rewarded in the same way that her husband was. She may have been disqualified because she advised her husband to end his suffering by cursing God and dying. (Job 2:9)  So it is within the realm of plausibility that these children - or some of them - had a different mother. However, this is a unmitigated joyful ending, so I think we may presume that she shared in the "happily ever after."

**Conclusion**: Job's news children were born and raised from infancy, not created as adults. Whether Job's wife was their mother is not stated in the text, but given the general tenor of the ending, we may presume that she was included.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that Jesus was born as a baby from the natural pregnancy of Mary. This indicates that although the Lord is capable of miracles, He doesn't disrupt the natural order of His creation. If we believe this, then it follows that the children of Jobs born by the Lord's blessings would not be born as adults.

Furthermore, in this account, the scripture doesn't mention who the mother of the children was, nor are the names of the sons given. Instead, the names of all the daughters are provided, and it has been explicitly claimed that they received inheritance along with their brothers from Job. If you are interested in this, please feel free to ask a new question.